# Ubuntu 13.10 VirtualBox Error Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox

I have been trying for a few hours to get Virtual Box running in Ubuntu 13.10
Every time I try to run a virtual machine running 64 bit Arch Linux I get an error message that says:

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary

When I do what the error prompt tells me, I get another error saying that the directory doesn't exist.
I have done research on the forums, and I have found nothing that works.
It may be use full to know that I have Virtual Box installed from the Ubuntu Software Center, and not from virtualbox.org because whenever I try to run the .deb file downloaded from there, Ubuntu Software Center doesn't let me use it for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
J

Comment: Have you tried doing `sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms` at all?

Comment: Have you tried to start the module manually? sudo service virtualbox start It should start the service (if it's istalled for your kernel). If it tells you is not, try reinstalling virtualbox, it should build the module and reinstall it.

Comment: no I haven't but i will right now

Comment: yea i just tried it and it didn't work. invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.

Comment: Did you try running `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` as the error message requested ? If so, what error message did you get ?

Comment: it said that the directory doesn't exist...I looked into the init.d directory and there was a folder called virtualbox but no folder called vboxdrv

Comment: I just tried it again and i got this `sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found`

Comment: How did you install virtualbox ? and it is `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` (note the "setup" )

Comment: I installed virtualbox via `sudo apt-get virtualbox` and yes i did type setup and got the previously stated error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem running on Ubuntu 12.04 - it happened after last `kernel` update

I solved by re-installing virtual box

`sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.6-91406 .. .deb`