# Multiple Problems while installing VMware Player with Kernel Headers

Tags: kernel, 64-bit, vmware-player

Sorry, pretty long problem

First some background: I was running Ubuntu 13.10 x64 in my laptop. I just upgraded to 14.04 few weeks back.  The output of the `uname -a` currently on my system are

`Linux ubuntu 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Now, I downloaded the `VMware-Player-6.0.2-1744117.x86_64.bundle` and tried to install it on my Laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
I installed VMWare-Player bundle usual way via

`sudo sh VMware-Player-6.0.2-1744117.x86_64.bundle`

After that, I tried to run the VMWare Player by searching through the search dock and clicking on its icon. I get this window
[image: Kernel Headers not found]

I googled the problem and found many people had faced such similar problem but with many different solutions. Unfortunately, none worked for me.

One was to install the header via this command

`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

I tried it and got the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic' has no installation candidate
```

This was scary.

Then I tried to another solution

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

again for no luck. `Failed to setup build environment.`

Then I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/43953/37001)
I was totally confused then because the terminal showed, the path `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux`   i.e.
`/lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include/linux` didn't exists!

Then I executed the following commands to clear my doubt:

```
$ cd /lib/modules
$:/lib/modules$ ls
3.11.0-19-generic  3.13.0-24-generic
$:/lib/modules$ ls 3.11.0-19-generic 3.13.0-24-generic
3.11.0-19-generic:
initrd  modules.alias      modules.builtin      modules.dep      modules.devname  modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin
kernel  modules.alias.bin  modules.builtin.bin  modules.dep.bin  modules.order    modules.symbols  updates

3.13.0-24-generic:
build
```

I am totally confused about whats wrong with my system and what should I do now? 
Thanks!

Comment: Similar case https://askubuntu.com/questions/405633/virtualbox-4-3-on-ubuntu-13-10-unable-to-run-vm/406400#406400

Comment: @Sneetsher: Since this question is specifically for VMware Player, could you please adapt the answer and cover this specific question?

Comment: Last posting solved my issue too.
was 3.11 kernel with headers missing and unavailable.
Now uname -a reports 3.13 and VM Workstation works fine. Thank you for your replies and Answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installed kernel was obsolete. Its headers is not any more in the repository. So the best thing to do is to update the kernel to last version in the repository.

To enable auto update for the kernel, install `linux-generic` which is a meta package to keep current version of the kernel & its headers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

For some reason this meta wasn't installed while upgrade for you. If it didn't work, then use Synaptic to install its headers or upgrade/install to the last kernel release (search for "linux").