# VMWare Player installing on ubuntu 14.04 missing headers

Tags: vmware

I'm trying to install VMWare Player on ubuntu 14.04 and I'm running into problems: headers are missing.

Similar question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461881/multiple-problems-while-installing-vmware-player-with-kernel-headers), checked answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware), but nothing works.

I tried to apply patch as well as described [here](http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2014/01/vmware-player-601-on-ubuntu-1404-alpha.html), but it didn't work as well.
I'm about to install the latest version 6.03.

Does anyone know how this could be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many install and uninstall, i have decided to install virtualbox and I have experienced similar issue.

Finally - with all sort of combinations found on the web I followed following steps:

added virtualbox from [original site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions)

**sudo apt-get remove dkms build-essential linux-headers-***

**sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)**

sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.3 --purge

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3

this worked, except that the extension pack was missing, so I did this:
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.10-93012.vbox-extpack

sudo adduser admin vboxusers

rebooted  the system

then clicked on the extpack which was in home folder

all worked fine.

For being sure, I have rebooted the system again

still all fine

and installed vmare as well without any issues.

Hope this will help to someone.

The key was to remove and re-install the headers.