# VirtualBox error kernel headers

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm with Ubuntu 15.04 and I'm trying to create an emulator (genymotion), but when run virtualbox, i got the error:

> Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
>   Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
>   Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-30-generic cannot be found.
>   Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic package,
>   or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
>    ...failed!
>     (Failed, trying without DKMS)
>   Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
>     (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)

I performed

```
uname -a
```

And the result is:

> Linux douglas 3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 12 22:06:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Someone help me?Already I uninstalled and installed again.

Comment: Why are you running Utopic kernel with the Vivid OS?

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic` from a terminal window and reboot the host when completed.

Comment: Appeared this message:  E: Impossível encontrar o pacote linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic

Comment: Did you install the new kernel for your Ubuntu 15.04?  Ubuntu 15.04 by default comes with kernel 3.19.

Comment: I do not know, I am new to linux.

Comment: Type in `lsb_release -a` from the terminal window, and what does it say?

Comment: No LSB modules are available
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.04
Release: 15.04
Codename: vivid

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid` from a terminal window

Comment: E: Impossível encontrar o pacote linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic` from the terminal window.

Comment: E: O pacote 'linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic' não possui candidato para instalação

Comment: What does `sudo update-grub` produce?

Comment: Generating grub configuration file ...
Atenção: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Encontrado imagem linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Encontrado imagem initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
concluído

Comment: The kernel has been removed.  Follow the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels) to reinstall the 3.19 kernel.  You will need to boot your system from the Ubuntu 15.04 LiveCD / Install CD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox 4.3 on Ubuntu 13.10 unable to run VM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/405633/virtualbox-4-3-on-ubuntu-13-10-unable-to-run-vm)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the kernel for Ubuntu Vivid. Probably it was remove by accident. So here are the steps.

```
# Install latest kernel
$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic

# Restart your machine ...

# Recompile the kernel module for Virtualbox
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

I had the same problem after trying to install **Virtualbox 5.0** on Ubuntu 15.04 and I think I 've removed also the kernel while purging the virtualbox packages.

Comment: OP is missing 3.19 kernel image too. That is some bud in upgrade.