# How can I fit the Ubuntu desktop to the screen in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 in VirtualBox 4.2.34 on a Windows 7 host.

I can't get the desktop to fit the screen.

I installed Guest Additions and allocated enough of video memory, but no dice.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the resolution through Ubuntu's settings?

Comment: What is your settings in the View menu?

Comment: Did you install them through the repositories or through the VirtualBox guest additions virtual CD? Did you reboot after that?

Comment: Android Dev:
yes, I've tried changing the resolution through Ubuntu's settings. It is in best resolution.

Comment: Melebius: I checked all of them!

Comment: Andrea Lazzarotto: through the VirtualBox guest additions virtual CD. Yes I did.

Comment: I know this is kinda obvious but it wasn't mentioned if you did it or not... Did you reboot the Ubuntu VM?

Comment: I voted to close this question as it old and lack information, like err message that OP mention in comment. in below answer https://askubuntu.com/a/792297/26246 . low chance to debug but could be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/405633/26246

Answer (score 1):

You need install the virtualbox guest additions:

- In the VM's menu: click "**Devices**" -> "**Insert Guest Additions CD Image**" (The guest additions cd image will be mount in your guest's cdrom"
- Run

  .{path_to_your_CDROM_mount_in_the_GUEST}/VboxLinuxAddition.run
- Restart your VM
- Now, with the correct driver installed and loaded: "You have to select "Auto-resize guest display" on "View" menu".

Hope this help!

Comment: This partially worked for me, but I needed additional steps. I was doing it on RHEL, so I'm writing it as comment not answer, but on Ubuntu it may be similar. Firstly add additional packages. `dnf install tar bzip2 kernel-devel-$(uname -r) kernel-headers perl gcc make elfutils-libelf-devel ` ([source](https://linuxconfig.org/virtualbox-install-guest-additions-on-redhat-8)). Then there was a problem with `mount.vboxsf already defined` and here is what helped me: [link](https://forum.linuxconfig.org/t/virtualbox-install-guest-additions-on-redhat-8-linuxconfig-org/2566/27)

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the guest addons as [described in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/792315/650986), I noticed that on a fresh Xubuntu the kernel modules could not been buld because of missing dependencies. So I installed them first using

```
apt-get install -y gcc make perl
```

Now I could run `VboxLinuxAddition.run` from the mounted ISO file. After a reboot, the guest addons were installed. *Auto-resize guest display* worked, after disabling and re-enabling it in the *View* menu of the host.

Answer (score -1):

You have to select "Auto-resize guest display" on "View" menu.

If this doesn't work, then you have done something wrong at Guest Additions installation.

Comment: there is an error when I try to install Guest Additions, one of the lines failed!
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the OpenGL support module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)

Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not installing
X Window System drivers.
 ...done.
Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.
Press Return to close this window...

Comment: you inserted the cd? and then?
did you sudo sh autorun.sh at the /media/<yourcd> location?

Answer (score -1):

Installing gcc make and perl solved my issue.

```
sudo apt install gcc make perl
```

Hope this helps someone.